# ANTLR validate wrong string

Tags: java, antlr4, dsl

I have following antlr 4.7 grammar. It needs to validate open and closed quotes, brckets and so on. So, string like '"(" will not validate, but it is. Antlr plug-in of intellij Idea and Eclipse can't build syntax tree and show me where I'm wrong.

So, where is my problem? Please, see grammar bellow. What I need to do to make the string not validatable and why antlr plug-in can't build the syntax tree for it?

```
grammar WellFormedGrammarValidator;

main_program
:
    (
        string
        | string_one_quote
        | expression
        | multiline_comment
        | xml_comment
        | one_line_comment
        | EscapeSequence
    )*
;

one_line_comment
:
    ONE_LINE_COMMENT
;

multiline_comment
:
    MULTILINE_COMMENT
;

xml_comment
:
    XML_COMMENT
;

string
:
    QUOTED
;

string_one_quote
:
    QUOTED_SINGLE
;

expression
:
    not_string_term
    | '{'
    (
        main_program?
    ) '}'
    | '['
    (
        main_program?
    ) ']'
    | '('
    (
        main_program?
    ) ')'
;

not_string_term
:
    NOT_STRING_CHAR+
;

NOT_STRING_CHAR
:
    (
        ~['"']
    )
    | '|'
;

QUOTED
:
    '"' StringCharacters? '"'
    | CharacterLiteral
;

QUOTED_SINGLE
:
    '\'' StringCharactersOneQuote '\''
;

CharacterLiteral
:
    '\'' SingleCharacter '\''
    | '\'' EscapeSequence '\''
;

fragment
SingleCharacter
:
    ~['\\]
;

fragment
StringCharacters
:
    StringCharacter+
;

fragment
StringCharactersOneQuote
:
    StringCharacterOneQuote+
;

StringCharacterOneQuote
:
    (
        ~'\''
    )
    | '\\\\\''
    | EscapeSequence
;

fragment
StringCharacter
:
    (
        ~["]
    )
    | '\\\\"'
    | EscapeSequence
;

EscapeSequence
:
    '\\' [btnfr"'\\]
;

ONE_LINE_COMMENT
:
    '#' ~[\r\n]*
;

MULTILINE_COMMENT
:
    '/*' .*? '*/'
;

XML_COMMENT
:
    '<!--' .*? '-->'
;

WS
:
    [ \t\r\n\u000C]+ -> skip
;
```

Comment: Could you give an example of your input ? If I run this grammar with 4.6 and the input `(NL`, I have an error `line 2:0 missing ')' at '<EOF>'`, which means that the grammar is correctly expecting a closing parenthesis. To display the syntax tree, use the command `grun WellFormedGrammarValidator main_program -gui t.text` in a terminal window (replace t.text with your input file name). Define `grun` with `alias grun='java org.antlr.v4.gui.TestRig'` and you probably need a CLASSPATH, for me it's `export CLASSPATH=".:/usr/local/lib/antlr-4.6-complete.jar"`.

Comment: But, when I do it with antlr 4.7 have an empty errors set

Comment: There is a problem

Comment: Of course adjust the CLASSPATH to your 4.7 file.